# Is there a way to have intuitive saving using the System.IO reference in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, save, devexpress

I'm trying to have an intuitive saving process. This will allow clients to save their reports without specifying a name. As an example, the default name will be 'GenerateNotice.pdf'. On a second save, I would like it to automatically detect the original report and automatically populate the name as 'GenerateNotice1.pdf'. On the third save, it would automatically populate 'GenerateNotice2.pdf', etc, etc.

This is what I'm currently using:

```
static void ThreadMethodReport(List<Notice> notices, string template, bool reprint)
        {
            XtraReport report = CreateReport(notices, template, reprint);
            PdfExportOptions pdfExportOptions = SetExportOptions();
            SaveFileDialog save = SetSaveFileDialogOptions();

            DialogResult dialogResult = save.ShowDialog();
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string saveLocation;
                using (FileStream stream = (FileStream)save.OpenFile())
                {
                    saveLocation = stream.Name;
                }
                report.ExportToPdf(saveLocation, pdfExportOptions);
            }
        }

private static SaveFileDialog SetSaveFileDialogOptions()
        {
            string fileNameInitial = @"GenerateNotice.pdf";
            string fileNameCurrent = fileNameInitial;
            int count = 0;
            while (File.Exists(fileNameCurrent))
            {
                count++;
                fileNameCurrent = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNameInitial)
                     + count.ToString()
                     + Path.GetExtension(fileNameInitial);
            }
            return new SaveFileDialog()
            {
                Filter = "PDF Format|*.pdf",
                Title = "Save infraction as",
                FileName = fileNameCurrent
            };
        }
```

However, it will only ever identify the initial file and no subsequent ones.

Does this have something to do with me using IIS and it expecting the files to be saved somewhere in the IIS root directory?

Comment: Isn't `SaveFileDialog` a class from WinForms, not WebForms/Asp.net?

Comment: @gunr2171 I'll be honest, I did not notice that until you mentioned it. Maybe that's my issue. I'm going to try and give something like this a try: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/468019/SaveFileDialog-equivalent-for-a-webpage

Comment: Please note that if you need to save something on the client, you will not have access to the file system, so you cannot decide the file name.

Comment: @PalleDue You can certainly offer the client a filename, and you can even keep track of what you've offered in the past to ensure that the name you suggest is unique compared to past suggestions, or perhaps add the date/time to the file name.